# Advanced logging with NodeJs: TypeError: X is not iterable

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have created this funcion to log into a file with verbosity level set to info, max 5 files and 5 MB for each 
and a complete full log (verbosity level debug) in the terminal but the different level should use different colors.

```
private initialize(): void {

        var winston = require('winston');
        winston.emitErrs = true;

        var logger = new winston.Logger({
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.File({
                    level: 'info',
                    filename: './logs/all-logs.log',
                    handleExceptions: true,
                    json: true,
                    maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
                    maxFiles: 5,
                    colorize: false
                }),
                new winston.transports.Console({
                    level: 'debug',
                    handleExceptions: true,
                    json: false,
                    colorize: true
                })
            ],
            exitOnError: false
        });

        module.exports = logger;
        module.exports.stream = {
            write: function(message : any, encoding : any){
                logger.info(message);
            }
        };

    }
```

but I have this error when starting the app.

```
App encountered an unhandled rejection at
Promise: [object Promise]
Reason:
        this.enableTransports is not iterable
        TypeError: this.enableTransports is not iterable
    at LoggingService.isAtLeastOneTransportLevelActive
```

enableTransports is used here

```
private createLoggerWithTransports(customLevels: any): void {
        // Create Logger with transports
        const configuration: Configuration = this.configService.configuration;
        this.enableTransports = LoggingService.getEnabledTransports(configuration);
        const opts = {
            levels: customLevels.levels,
            level: LogLevels.TRACE.label,
            transports: LoggingService.createEnabledTransports(this.enableTransports),
            exitOnError: false
        };
        this.logger = winston.createLogger(opts);
    }
```

and

```
 private static createEnabledTransports(enabledTransports: any[]): any[] {
        const transports = enabledTransports
            .map((transportConfig: any) => LoggingService.createTransportFromConfig(transportConfig));
        return transports;
    }
```

and

```
  private static getEnabledTransports(configuration: Configuration): any[] {
        const transports = configuration.logging.transports
            .filter((c: any) => <any>c.enabled === true);
        return transports;
    }


static createTransportFromConfig(transportConfig) {
        switch (transportConfig.transport) {
            case 'Console':
                const consoleLogRecordConverter = this.buildLogRecordConverter(transportConfig);
                const consoleOpts = {
                    level: transportConfig.minLevel,
                    handleExceptions: false,
                    format: format.combine(format.colorize({ level: true, message: false }), format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }), format.printf((info) => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level.toUpperCase()}: ${info.message}`))
                };
                return new winston.transports.Console(consoleOpts);
            case 'File':
                const fileLogRecordConverter = this.buildLogRecordConverter(transportConfig);
                const fileOpts = {
                    level: transportConfig.minLevel,
                    filename: transportConfig.fileName,
                    dirname: transportConfig.dirName,
                    maxfiles: transportConfig.maxFiles,
                    maxsize: transportConfig.maxSize,
                    zippedarchive: transportConfig.zippedArchive,
                    tailable: true,
                    handleexceptions: false,
                    datepattern: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                    format: format.combine(format.colorize({ level: true, message: false }), format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }), format.printf((info) => fileLogRecordConverter.getLogMessage(info)))
                };
                return new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)(fileOpts);
            default: {
                throw new Error(`Logger Transport ${transportConfig.type} not supported !`);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add the code where `this.enableTransports` is used? Also are you trying to use winston on browser side?

Comment: Show us definition of `createEnabledTransports` function?

Comment: Check why your function `getEnabledTransports` doesn't return an iterable `[]`, or post it here as well...

Comment: @sandro-rey - is there a for-loop somewhere in your code that uses `this.enableTransports`? Usually that's what causes the `is not iterable` error (when it tries to read `[Symbol.iterator]` on an object that does not have an iterator).
Also, you might have a typo in your code - some functions use `enableTransports` and some say `enabledTransports`. Maybe there's some omitted code that tries to use one instead of the other.

Comment: Isn't `this.enableTransports` used inside `isAtLeastOneTransportLevelActive`? The error comes from there, maybe it makes sense to provide the implementation of this method as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that at the moment you want to iterate through `this.enableTransports`, it is a Promise object, and not an array or collection.

So `LoggingService.getEnabledTransports(configuration)` is doing (or calling another function that does) an asynchronous operation.

Maybe `LoggingService.createTransportFromConfig(transportConfig))` is doing something like checking a DB or opening a file to pick up the configuration.

If that is the case, then you could handle the promise and make sure it finishes before retuning it.

Can we see the code inside `LoggingService.createTransportFromConfig(transportConfig))`?

Thanks!